# Visual Studio Build Events not equal condition

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to have a not equal condition in build events ?

Like this:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) != Debug xcopy ...
```

Note that this is build event (batch-like syntax), not MSBuild task (which indeed supports != ).

Comment: No, it doesn't work, it seems that '!=' is not accepted by the compiler

Comment: This is a bit of a hack, but you could make it work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19089118/656243

Comment: IMO this is not a duplicate. The OP is asking about a "not equal" operator in build event syntax in general, not specifically about the debug build condition; my suggestion: According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms165412.aspx), build event syntax is DOS command syntax, so this should work: if $(ConfigurationName) NEQ Debug xcopy ...

Comment: Duplicate covers many options for "else" branch... Also I think simple `neq` should work too (as VS basically runs bat file to run events. You can get all bat comparison operators in CMD by typing `help if`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:**

My bad, I thought it's for MSBuild. But if it's for only Build event than it will work like `batch` script

```
if not "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Debug" (
  echo "hello world"
)
```

**For MSBuild**

It's like following

```
Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='DEBUG'"
```

ex:

```
<When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'!='DEBUG' ">
....
</When>
```

See details [MSBuild condition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx)